# Where is the Main Interface setting for my iOS project in XCode 14

Tags: xcode

I am creating some view programmatically and hard to find the Main Interface field under Deployment info . That was easy to find previously so i am not sure if something changed with the new Xcode. [image]

Answer (score 14):

Go to the `info` tab in the project target settings.
Under `Custom iOS Target Properties` delete the `Main storyboard file base name` item.

You'll also have to delete the `Storyboard Name` item here the same way I expect you would have in the `info.plist` file. It is located in the same location it was in the `info.plist` file in `Application Scene Manifest` -> `Scene Configuration` -> `Application Session Role` -> `Item 0 (Default Configuration)`

[image: Where to find items to delete]